# Is it possible to create a single executable file of a Ruby on Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to create a single executable file for any rails project.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for solution.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can, using [the gem ruby-packer](https://github.com/pmq20/ruby-packer).

- Compiling a Rails application

  1. rails new yours
  2. cd yours
  3. rubyc bin/rails
  4. ./a.out server (or a.exe server on Windows)

Comment: Its not creating the output file for me.